# How to print spaces between words when trying to decrypt a text message from an input file, to an output file in C++?

Tags: c++

For example, let's say you have this encrypted text message `"ASBBU KQMCF"` in `input.txt`, and when you decrypt it, it will become `"HELLO WORLD"` in `output.txt`.

As you can see, `"A"` becomes `"H"`, `"S"` becomes `"E"`, `"B"` becomes `"L"`, `"U"` becomes `"O"`, `"K"` becomes `"W"`, `"Q"` becomes `"O"`, `"M"` becomes `"R"`, `"C"` becomes `"L"`, and `"F"` becomes `"D"`.

The problem is that, when I decrypt the whole text, it's in one piece and there are no spaces. It looks like this: `"HELLOWORLD"`, while it has to look like this: `"HELLO WORLD"`. Is it possible to read the text and decrypt it while retaining the spaces that are between words?

I wrote a code that reads a letter and changes it to the correct one, as shown in the code, but I can't figure out how to make spaces between words.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char ch;
  ifstream read("input.txt");
  ofstream write("output.txt");

  while(read>>ch){
    switch (ch) {
      case 'A':
        ch='H';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'S':
        ch='E';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'B':
        ch='L';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'U':
        ch='O';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'K':
        ch='W';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'Q':
        ch='O';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'M':
        ch='R';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'C':
        ch='L';
        write<<ch;
    }
    switch(ch){
      case 'F':
        ch='D';
        write<<ch;
    } 
  }
  read.close();
  write.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: just output a space after you output each decoded word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator>>` skips leading whitespace by default, and then reads until whitespace is encountered.  As such, your code will never see space characters in your `ch` variable.

Since you want to preserve whitespace, you should use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>`.  Read the file line-by-line into a `std::string`, and then you can manipulate the characters in each `std::string` as needed.

Also, you are misusing `switch`.  You don't need a separate `switch` for each `case`.  That is no better than just using a bunch of `if-else` blocks. You can have multiple `case`s in a single `switch` (that is its primary design - to make a selection from multiple choices).

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string str;
  ifstream read("input.txt");
  ofstream write("output.txt");

  while (getline(read, str)) {
    for(char &ch : str) {
      switch (ch) {
        case 'A':
          ch = 'H';
          break;
        case 'S':
          ch = 'E';
          break;
        case 'B':
          ch = 'L';
          break;
        case 'U':
          ch = 'O';
          break;
        case 'K':
          ch = 'W';
          break;
        case 'Q':
          ch = 'O';
          break;
        case 'M':
          ch = 'R';
          break;
        case 'C':
          ch = 'L';
          break;
        case 'F':
          ch = 'D';
          break;
      }
    }
    write << str << '\n';
  }
  read.close();
  write.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Also, just on a side note: your "encryption" has a flaw - you have both `B` and `C` being "encrypted" into `L`, and both `Q` and `U` being "encrypted" into `O`.  Which means you will lose data on "decryption" if either `L` and/or `O` are present, since you won't know which original characters to "decrypt" them back to.  Each unique input characters needs a unique output character.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate your help. And yes correct I made a mistake with some letters being encrypted into the same letter. (Tried to create a similar problem that I have to do for homework). Also another question is that why do we need to use a "for loop" is a "while loop" not enough? And last question what does "char&ch:str" mean? Apologies for the dumb questions, I'm not that good at C++ and I'm new here

Comment: C++ has many types of loops. Use whichever one you are most comfortable with. The `while` loop is reading the file a whole line at a time, so a 2nd loop is needed to access the individual characters of each line. `for(char &ch : str)` is a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). You could use `for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size() ++i){ char &ch = str[i]; ... }` instead, if that is what you are more comfortable with.  Although, [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) might make more sense than a manual loop.

Answer (score -1):

im not sur about what u want to do .

but like i see before u can do unique switch.

and use default case where u write actual char like

`write<<ch;`

on this example i use switch to print hello world and change some letter

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello, world!";
    for (char c : str)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'H':
                std::cout << "S" << std::endl;
                break;
            case 'e':
                std::cout << "Q" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << c  << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you think you can reuse this example to fix your issue?

Comment: How does this improve on the other answer?